# How to implement authorization for Telegram using tg?

Tags: php, api, telegram

I'm in the process of implementation of the simple Telegram chat on php, and the question was raised: how to perform the authorization on Telegram, if I decided to use tg as a client and php-telegram-cli-client as a wrapper for interaction with this client via unix file socket?

https://github.com/vysheng/tg

https://github.com/zyberspace/php-telegram-cli-client

In this client, before you can send messages and use commands, you need to authorize yourself. You run:

```
bin/telegram-cli -k tg-server.pub
```

and after that console app asks you for your mobile phone and verifying code. But when you're trying to change your user you realize that you simply don't have any tools to do it. I tried to change RSA key to any other one, but it didn't help me much.

Should I change tool for my task (several users authorize on my site and drop in chat room created for them) or I haven't paid attention to some details that could help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do, but I have gone down this road too. Vshengs Telegram CLI under Linux works ok-ish, but he tends to change to code constantly without thinking of backwards compatibility, so be prepared for high a  maintenance solution. Also, it is fairly complicated as a whole in combination with PHP (or any language for that matter)

If i were you I would look at the official Telegram Bot API

Look at https://core.telegram.org/bots

Comment: One good thing about the BOT API is that it does not require a phone numer